# Message is Not displayed (vue.js 2)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

ERROE 9:5  error  'Vue' is not defined  no-undef
I added "import Vue from 'vue'" to the first line of the script. The error disappeared, but the message was not displayed.

Sorry for the rudimentary question.

```
views/About.vue
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is an about page</h1>
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: "#about",
  data: {
    message: "Hello Vue!",
  },
});
</script>

main.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Hello !'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Just do like this.

Comment: It was displayed correctly. Thank you for your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you have already mounted your vue instance in your `main.js`, so there's no need to create another vue instance and mount it again in the `About.vue` file.

You only need the following lines of code in the `About.vue` file

##### In Vue 2

```vue
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is an about page</h1>
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: {
    message: "Hello World!"
  }
}
</script>
```

##### In Vue 3

In vue 3, the data property is now a method.

```vue
<template>
  <div class="about">
    <h1>This is an about page</h1>
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
   return {
    message: "Hello World!"
   }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's recommended for Vue 2's `data` hook to be a function that returns an object as well

Comment: You can check yourself, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods. Let me know if I've missed out anything.. :-)

Comment: You haven't miss anything. But it's worth noting that using object on data is not recommended.  You can check here yourself, https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function

Comment: That's only when you are registering a component using `Vue.component` that the data has to be a function in vue2 or do you have a different opinion?

Comment: Very well. if you insist it is, I wont stop you.

Comment: No I'm genuinely curious. Because in their data & properties documentation they shown the code with a object. It's only in vue3 documentation that it's consistent everywhere. :-)

Comment: You must use data as a function when the component is a reusable component, otherwise all components will reference the same `data` object. Although in this case I think OP is creating an `About` page which will only have a single instance, so having data as an object is fine.

Comment: Yep @Mythos that's what I was informing Karma Blackshaw about. Thanks for clarifying. Karma blacksaw thanks for your time.

Comment: No poblem @Salvino :)

Comment: My pakckage.json is "vue":"^2.6.11". In Vue 2, I got "error `data` property in component must be a function vue/no-shared-component-". However, I was able to see "Hello Vue!" by adding the function that you and others sent me. Thank you very much.